# Inform users when they are about to hit the monthly question limit

Tags: feature-request, monthly-question-limit

I was quite surprised today when I saw the message telling me that I can no longer post questions because of the 50 questions limit. So I think it would be nice if users were informed earlier that they are going to be blocked from asking questions.

Maybe there could be message at 30 questions? For example:

**Note: you have asked 30 of your 50 monthly questions. Once you reach the limit of 50 per month, you will have to wait before asking more questions.**

Then the same message at 40, 45, etc.

Comment: See also [Suggestions on improving the 50 question per month limit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96610).

Comment: Erm, how are you going to use that bit of information?  Are you going to spend more time researching the problem on your own before posting?  The intent is clearly that you should do this anyway, without knowing how close you are to the limit.

Comment: @Hans Passant, the problem is that most users don't know there's a 50 question limit, so they end up being temporarily blocked without warning. Adding these messages will have two advantages: 1) users will now know about the question limit 2) They will ask less questions to remain below the limit.

Comment: Of course they know.  You know now too.  It is a once-a-month warning.  This is intentional.

Comment: @Hans Passant, not sure what you mean when you say it's intentional, I seriously doubt the lack of warnings is by design. Even for daily votes there are regular warnings, even though not being able to vote for a day is no big deal compared to being blocked from asking questions for several days. All I'm suggesting is to inform users. There's no reason why this question limit should be kept a secret until it's too late.