# How to increase quota for questions?

Tags: support, questions, rate-limiting, limits, monthly-question-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [50 question per month limit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89217/50-question-per-month-limit)

I hit the limit of 50 questions per 30 days. How I can increase my quota?

Comment: Not. Choose the questions you really need to ask, you won't get more than 50 per 30 days.

Comment: Come back in a month. Quota increased. Or, actually look at the type of questions you're posting and stop flooding.

Comment: I work with java, java server faces, oracle, php. What I'm going to do without the help from stack overflow?

Comment: Have you tried the site search at all?

Comment: I always ask about errors in code or how to fix a problem - things that are very specific

Comment: Try offering the devs $1000/month to ask more :P

Comment: By the way is there any similar web site like stackoverflow.com where I can write with developers very fast?

Comment: @user989100 Have you tried searching for the specific error messages you get?

Comment: *I always ask about errors in code or how to fix a problem - things that are very specific* -- shouldn't those be closed as "too localized" then? (Reading your reasoning, I'm happy there's an automatic limit then.)

Comment: Yes - Google and some books

Comment: Never mind thread is closed.

Comment: What do you mean with *"thread is closed"*?

Comment: Of all the questions you've asked so far on SO, you only have a net score of +20. That's less than 1/4 of a vote per question. So, the rate-limit appears to be doing a good job.

Comment: If you're this dependent on Stack Overflow, you may be in the wrong line of business. We shouldn't be doing your debugging for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [50 question per month limit?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89217/50-question-per-month-limit), [Is there a limit on how many questions I can ask?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4359/is-there-a-limit-on-how-many-questions-i-can-ask)

Comment: Since you can't ask any more questions, spend some time posting some answers. You've only posted 9 in the past 5 months. We do expect people to pay it forward by answering other people's questions.

Answer (score 25):

Short answer: you can't.

We consider 50 questions in 30 days to be a fairly generous allotment. That's almost 2 questions per day. What are you working on that you're generating that many questions?

Looking at your questions, I see that a lot of them are similar. Perhaps you would benefit from reading a few tutorials on the technologies you're working with. I recommend taking a step back and checking whether your questions have already been asked by other users or whether you can do some research first and get to the bottom of the problem.

Comment: But anyways, why this limit are even exists? I'll clarify -- while I do agree with you that 50 is quite big number and will suit to the **vast majority** of users, generally, I don't like an idea limiting a user in a such way.

Comment: @om I think the general feeling (and I wholeheartedly agree with it) is that a  programmer who *needs* to ask more than 50 questions a month is either in the wrong job, should read a book or get training instead, is not doing their research properly, or is not developing at all professionally.

Comment: @om-nom-nom It's largely an anti-spamming measure. Stack Overflow isn't intended to be the place you run to with every little thing. You are expected to do your own research first. Most people never even come close to hitting this limit.

Comment: @om-nom-nom It's to prevent abuse. SO is a free service, with users willingly giving their time to answer questions. When someone asks that many questions, they are generally not giving back to the community, and being extremely selfish

Comment: Anna, just out of curiosity, does this limit apply to all users, or only new ones?  I could go ask about 45 or so more questions, but asking you should be simpler :)

Comment: @AdamRackis It applies to everybody far as I know.

Comment: @om-nom-nom: Have a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96610/suggestions-on-improving-the-50-question-per-month-limit, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4359/is-there-a-limit-on-how-many-questions-i-can-ask, and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89217/50-question-per-month-limit for previous discussion of the limit.

Comment: @IuliusCæsar thanks, I've got a look *p.s. Funny, but I haven't met mr. Blankman on SO*